# PHP: Función stripos no es capaz de localizar palabra clave en cadena que empieza por ella

Tags: php

Estoy intentando localizar una serie de palabras clave en unas cadenas con la función strpos (también he probado con stripos, para evitar problemas con las mayúsculas), pero se me presenta el siguiente problema: cuando la cadena comienza por esa palabra, no es capaz de localizarla; lo ilustraré con el caso que me ocupa:

Tengo un array con una serie de palabras clave que hacen referencia a estilos musicales:

```
$estilos = array("Rock", "Pop", "Punk", "Metal", "Folk", "Country");
```

Y una serie de subestilos que quiero relacionar con estos estilos en mi base de datos; la tabla de subestilos es muy amplia pero ahora mismo los que tengo que clasificar son seis:

```
(NULL, 'Anti Folk'),
(NULL, 'Garage Rock Revival'),
(NULL, 'Traditional Pop'),
(NULL, 'Rock & Roll'),
(NULL, 'Country Soul'),
(NULL, 'Britpop');
```

Bien, pues usando stripos para que determine si cada una de estas seis cadenas contiene alguna de las palabras clave del array, sólo localiza cuatro de ellas, las que incluyen la palabra clave en una posición que no sea la 0:

'Anti Folk', 'Garage Rock Revival', 'Traditional Pop' y 'Britpop'; 'Rock & Roll' y 'Country Soul', las ignora.

Una posible solución es modificar el array de palabras clave de la siguiente manera:

```
$estilos = array("ock", "op", "unk", "etal", "olk", "ountry");
```

Pero no quiero hacer esto... ¿Se os ocurre qué puede ser?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

EDITO:

```
foreach($datos as $indice => $duo) 
{
    $id_subestilo = $duo['id_subestilo'];
    $nombre_subestilo = $duo['nombre_subestilo'];

    for($i = 0; $i < count($estilos); $i++) 
    {   
        if(stripos($nombre_subestilo, $estilos[$i]))
        {
```

Tengo el array $datos con los subestilos y sus ids, procedentes de mi base de datos, y lo comparo con el array $estilos con las palabras clave... A partir del if se hace una conexión a la base de datos para saber qué id tiene el estilo con el que posiblemente esté relacionado el subestilo.

Comment: Puedes poner tu código para ver de qué manera estás usando stripos?

Comment: Acabo de editar mi entrada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en la forma en la que estás haciendo la comprobación:

```
if(stripos($nombre_subestilo, $estilos[$i]))
```

Como stripos y strpos regresan `0` cuando la cadena a buscar está al inicio (posición 0), el resultado es evaluado como falso.

En tu caso debes hacer:

```
if(stripos($nombre_subestilo, $estilos[$i]) !== false)
```

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

**Las funciones [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php) y [stripos()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strripos.php) de PHP te devuelven la posición de la aparición del string buscado o *FALSE* si no se encuentra**. ***No devuelven un booleano*** en caso de encontrase el string buscado, sino su posición, partiendo de 0, entonces si haces una comprobación tipo:

```
if (strpos("una prueba", "una")) {
   echo "encontrada";
} else {
   echo "no encontrada";
}
```

el resultado impreso será "no encontrada". Este resultado se da por que se encuentra el string buscado en la primera posición, contando los caracteres previos, es decir 0, y 0 se evalúa como FALSE, así puede parecer que no se encuentra el string.

Para saber si el string se "encuentra", tendrías que hacer algo así:

```
if (strpos("una prueba", "una") || strpos("una prueba", "una") == 0) {
   echo "encontrada";
} else {
   echo "no encontrada";
}
```

Donde la condición comprueba si obtienes una posición *igual o mayor a 0*.

#### Aviso

Las funciones anteriores, deberán ser reemplazadas por [mb_strpos()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strpos.php) y [mb_stripos()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-stripos.php) en los casos en que las cadenas con que se trabaja tengan caracteres que no aparecen en lengua inglesa, como letras ñ, acentuadas, diéresis, etc. cuando se requiera el orden correcto de aparición. Las primera son más rápidas pero no devuelven la posición correcta del puntero.

Comment: Según php.net:

"Devuelve la posición donde está la aguja, en relación al inicio del string haystack (independiente de offset). Observe también que las posiciones de inicio de los string empiezan en 0, y no en 1.

Devuelve FALSE si no se encontró la aguja."

Comment: @Optigan correcto la devolución de *false* cuando no se encuentra el string buscado. Edito mi respuesta.